# Need a Map from List from Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, jpa, java-8, grouping

I am getting a list of object array from `@NamedQuery` (JPA)

```
List<Object[]> restinctionList = (List<Object[]> ) 
em.createNamedQuery("DocqryRestriction.getAllAdmnAndER").getResultList();
```

The Object array Containing two Long value 
example: `Object[] = {12345L,34533L}`

i want to group the list (restinctionList ) based on `Object[0]` key
like

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> groupList = restinctionList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy());
```

How can i write the `"restinctionList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(restinctionList.toArray()));"`

so that i can proper result

The raw data that has assign to Object array is

```
1 - 10068   
2 - 10069   
3 - 10070   
4 - 10080   
5 - 10100   102912

6 - 10100   102273

7 - 10100   
8 - 10124
```

I want the result as

```
Key 10068 value null
Key 10069 value null
...
...
key - 10100 value [null, 102912,102273]
....
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want as the key in your map?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of your data and how you are expecting the `Map` to result from it?

Comment: In your question you said `Object[0]` but here you are saying `Object[1]`. Also what happens if 2 arrays have the same first value? Will the rest of the numbers somehow be grouped together?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you mentioned a key in your question. I think you better clarify your question with some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Is there any chance that you want  for you to flatten your list?

Comment: yes Object[0] is the Key, By Mistaken i have written Object[1] as key

Comment: Object[0] is the key, on the basis of Object[0] i want to group the list to map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer of my question as

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestListObjectArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] obj = { 42628, 567898 };
    Object[] obj1 = { 426238, 5674898 };
    Object[] obj2 = { 42621, 5678498 };
    Object[] obj3 = { 42627, 5678698 };
    Object[] obj4 = { 42627, };
    Object[] obj5 = { 42627, 1000 };

    List<Object[]> listObjectArr = new ArrayList<>();
    listObjectArr.add(obj);
    listObjectArr.add(obj1);
    listObjectArr.add(obj2);
    listObjectArr.add(obj3);
    listObjectArr.add(obj4);
    listObjectArr.add(obj5);

    Map<Object, List<Object>> ObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Object[]> restinctionList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<List<?>> restinctionDummyList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object[] resArr : listObjectArr) {
        List<Object> targetList = Arrays.asList(resArr);
        restinctionDummyList.add(targetList);
    }
    restinctionDummyList.forEach(list -> {
        List<Object> tmpArrayList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        if (ObjectMap.get(list.get(0)) != null) {
            List<Object> resultList = ObjectMap.get(list.get(0));
            tmpArrayList.remove(0);
            resultList.addAll(tmpArrayList);
        } else {
            ObjectMap.put(list.get(0), tmpArrayList);           
        }
    });

    System.out.println(ObjectMap);
}
}
```

Output on console

```
{42627=[42627, 5678698, 1000], 42628=[42628, 567898], 426238=[426238, 5674898], 42621=[2621, 5678498]}
```

Comment: I have used some portion of code of Mr Novy. Thanks Novy

Comment: In your question, you mentioned you wanted to have `null` in the result.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a forEach

```
List<List<Long>>   restinctionList =  Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(10068L),
            Arrays.asList(10069L),
            Arrays.asList(10070L),
            Arrays.asList(10080L),
            Arrays.asList(10100L,102912L),
            Arrays.asList(10100L,102273L),
            Arrays.asList(10100L),
            Arrays.asList(10124L));

    Map< Long,List<Long>> countingrestinctionList =  new HashMap<>();
    restinctionList.forEach(list->{ 
        List<Long> tmpArrayList =   new ArrayList<>(list);
        if(countingrestinctionList.get(list.get(0))!=null) {
            List<Long> resultList=countingrestinctionList.get(list.get(0));
            tmpArrayList.remove(0);
            resultList.addAll(tmpArrayList);
        }else {
            tmpArrayList.set(0, null);
            countingrestinctionList.put(list.get(0),tmpArrayList ); 
        }
    });
    System.out.println(countingrestinctionList);
```

Answer:

```
{10080=[null], 10068=[null], 10100=[null, 102912, 102273], 10069=[null], 10070=[null], 10124=[null]}
```

Comment: tmpArrayList.set(0, null); is not required, if we add then result will be {10080=[null, null], 10068=[null, null], 10100=[null,null, 10124],

Comment: I can't see why it should. The "set" simply replaces the value at index 0 by null

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using a single stream statement

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object[]> restinctionList = Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{10068L},
                new Object[]{10069L},
                new Object[]{10070L},
                new Object[]{10080L},
                new Object[]{10100L, 102912L},
                new Object[]{10100L, 102273L},
                new Object[]{10100L},
                new Object[]{10124L}
                );
        Map<Object, ArrayList<Object>> result = restinctionList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        (Object[] e) -> e[0],
                        Collector.of(
                                () -> {ArrayList<Object> e = new ArrayList<>(); e.add(null); return e;},
                                (ArrayList<Object> l, Object[] e) -> {if(e.length > 1){l.add(e[1]);}},
                                (ArrayList<Object> a, ArrayList<Object> b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a;})
                ))
                ;

        result.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Which give as output

```
10080=[null]
10100=[null, 102912, 102273]
10068=[null]
10069=[null]
10070=[null]
10124=[null]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you want to use `groupingBy` you, could do this:

```
private Map<Long, List<Long>> getMapGroupingBy(List<Object[]> list) {
    Map<Long, List<Long>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obs -> (Long)obs[0], Collectors.mapping(obs -> (obs.length>1?(Long)obs[1]:null), Collectors.toList())));
    return map2;
}
```

If you are more intended to get the result, and not on using `groupingBy()`, you could do like this:

```
private Map<Long, List<Long>> getMapForEach(List<Object[]> list) {
    Map<Long, List<Long>> map = new HashMap<>();
    list.stream().forEach(obs -> {
        map.computeIfAbsent((Long)obs[0], a -> new ArrayList<Long>()).add(obs.length>1?(Long)obs[1]:null);
    });
    return map;
}
```

If you print the `map` you get something like this :

```
{1234=[123, null, 678], 1223=[null], 1225=[345]}
```

Your input list should look like this:

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Object[] {1234l,123l});
list.add(new Object[] {1234l});
list.add(new Object[] {1234l,678l});
list.add(new Object[] {1223l});
list.add(new Object[] {1225l,345l});
```